# What is more secure showing 404 error or redirecting the user

Tags: web

In php suppose the user is not logged in and tries to access the /dashboard page, is showing 404 page more secure than redirecting the user to the login page, or both are same ?

Answer (score -1):

Redirecting user to the Login page is more secure than showing 404 error page